# selecting month end values in a time series query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table which has daily observations for some stocks.

```
     DatePrice  date 
     IndexLevel float
     Stock      nvarchar(7)
     Weight     float
```

However I am only interested in the month end values of the stocks. So say I want to query the table over the date range of 2017 I would only want 12 observations returned. However if the last day of the month is a weekend then there would be no value so it would need to get the last working day of the month. Is this possible?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.) Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `month()` function with window functions

select month(dateprice)

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by year(dateprice), month(dateprice)
                                order by dateprice desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
      where dateprice >= '2017-01-01' and dateprice < '2018-01-01'
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```